# using reduce function in multitprocessing

Tags: python, lambda, reduce, python-multithreading

I'm trying to use multithrpocessing class to process a 1000000 dataset, but I'm getting MaybeEncodingError,
here is what I'm trying to do in Jupyter notebook:
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import reduce

pool= Pool(4)
a = [x for x in range(1,1000000)]

def multi(lt):
    return reduce((lambda x,y: x*y), lt)

pool.map(multi,a)

Comment: Why not using `operator.mul` instead of `lambda x,y : x*y`?

Comment: At `pool.map` you apply the function `multi` to integer numbers. However the function `multi` need to have a list of numbers instead of a single number.

Comment: @Elmex80s I want return the reduced set of 1000000 dataset

Comment: Watch out for shadow naming, `list` already has a meaning in Python, better if you change the name. --- You map `multi` to an integer, but `multi` needs a list.

Comment: @user2717058, when you use `pool.map` and passing it your function and args, `pool.map` is actually assuming that you're passing elements in your list ***one by one***. Basically, the first run will be `multi(0)`, which in your case does not make any sense. My advice is that you use [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) from the `concurrent.futures` module and split your giant list into a list of lists and pool that way.